# Primefaces InputStream generating corrupted PDF in fileDownload

Tags: java, jsf, pdf, primefaces, inputstream

I need your help in solving the issue of generating a corrupted PDF file from an `InputStream` which is used in the `fileDownload` Component. I am having a PDF that is generated using the iText and then I am converting it to an `inputStream`, so I can use it as an input in the `fileDownload` component. After clicking on the download `commandButton`, I will download the file and open it, it will show a message:

> The Adobe Reader can not open the file "sample.pdf" because it is
>   either not supported file type or it is damaged

The bean code is:

```
private StreamedContent file;

public void createPdf() {
    try {
        Document doc = Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ByteArrayInputStream in ;
        PdfWriter writer;
        writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, out);
        doc.open();
        doc.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
        in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
        file = new DefaultStreamedContent(in, "application/pdf", "sample.pdf");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the jsf code is:

```
<p:commandButton value="Download" ajax="false"
        onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);"
        icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s" actionListener="#{pdf.createPdf}">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{pdf.file}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

So how to fix the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't there be `doc.close()` before you start coping bytes from `out`? Is the file also corrupted if you save it to hard drive instead of sending it to browser?

Comment: Thanks for the help. The OutputStream should be closed, as well as, the document,